# XSLT remove empty node from the created output and the output set in a variable

Tags: xslt

Could you please help to remove empty node, from the created output and the output set in a variable.
I have created xslt as follows

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
                xmlns:user="http://www.contoso.com"
                version="1.0">
  <xsl:variable name="books">
    <header>
    <book author="Michael Howard">Writing Secure Code</book>
    <book author="Michael Kay">XSLT Reference</book>
    </header>
    <item>
      <item1>item1</item1>
      <item2></item2>//remove this empty tag
      <item3></item3>//remove this empty tag
    </item>
    <summary>
      <summary1>
      <sum1>SUB1</sum1>
        <sum2></sum2> //remove this empty tag
      </summary1>
      <summary2>Summary2</summary2>
      <summary3>Summ3</summary3>
    </summary>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="$books"/>    
      <xsl:for-each select="msxsl:node-set($books)/node()">                
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
            <!--select="ms:node-set($completeDocument[1])/node()"/>-->           
      </xsl:for-each>  
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match= "*[not(@*|*|comment()|processing-instruction()) and normalize-space()='']"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

output has produced

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>Writing Secure CodeXSLT Referenceitem1item2SUB1sub2Summary2Summ3Writing Secure CodeXSLT Referenceitem1item2SUB1sub2Summary2Summ3
```

Expected output

```
 <header>
        <book author="Michael Howard">Writing Secure Code</book>
        <book author="Michael Kay">XSLT Reference</book>
        </header>
        <item>
            <item1>item1</item1> 
        </item>
        <summary>
          <summary1>
          <sum1>SUB1</sum1>
          </summary1>
          <summary2>Summary2</summary2>
          <summary3>Summ3</summary3>
        </summary>
```

Expected output has shown remove empty node.

Comment: Please add an example for expected output. I do not see what "empty node" you like to "remove".

Comment: please see my question.I have updated my question.Here I show my xslt, output that produced and the expected output. I have actually input one file and convert to another form.Hence I need to remove the empty node from the created output.So I have created a variable and remove empty node from that variable by calling template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you have written a template that ensures certain elements are not copied but for that approach to work you need to add the identity transformation template that copies the nodes you want to be copied and that keeps processing going on. Otherwise there are only the built-in templates that do not copy element nodes but simply process child nodes and output text nodes.

So you want something like

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
                xmlns:user="http://www.contoso.com"
                exclude-result-prefixes="xsl msxsl user"
                version="1.0">
  <xsl:variable name="books">
    <header>
    <book author="Michael Howard">Writing Secure Code</book>
    <book author="Michael Kay">XSLT Reference</book>
    </header>
    <item>
      <item1>item1</item1>
      <item2></item2>//remove this empty tag
      <item3></item3>//remove this empty tag
    </item>
    <summary>
      <summary1>
      <sum1>SUB1</sum1>
        <sum2></sum2> //remove this empty tag
      </summary1>
      <summary2>Summary2</summary2>
      <summary3>Summ3</summary3>
    </summary>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="msxsl:node-set($books)/node()"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match= "*[not(@*|*|comment()|processing-instruction()) and normalize-space()='']"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi Martin,One more doubt.Can I possible to remove the empty tag which has the child element is empty. I have given the inputfile here     <item>
      <item1></item1> //it is removed from output
      <item2>  //item2 is not removed from output
        <item2SubOne>       
        </item2SubOne>
        <item2SubTwo>
        </item2SubTwo>
      </item2>
    </item>

Comment: Consider to ask a new question where you put the new input sample and the wanted output clearly into the question body. I am afraid here in a comment it is difficult to exchange code samples.